# Calculating a matrix of term co-occurrences, including with themselves, within a window

Tags: computational-linguistics, quantitative-linguistics

Here I am building on [this question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3641/how-to-calculate-the-co-occurrence-between-two-words-in-a-window-of-text), adding the possibility that a term has been inserted within the window of another term of the same type.  Here, I have inserted an `A` as the third character, from the original example.

```
txt <- "A D A C E A D F E B A C E D"
```

producing a window size 2 (+/- 2 terms) context co-occurrence matrix:

```
        features
contexts A B C D E F
       A 2 1 3 3 4 1
       B 1 0 1 0 1 1
       C 3 1 0 2 2 0
       D 3 0 2 0 3 1
       E 4 1 2 3 0 1
       F 1 1 0 1 1 0
```

**Question:** Is this the correct way to compute the co-occurrence of `A` with itself?  And should the first A be considered within the window of itself twice, once counting the second A (index position 3, counting from 1) in the context window of the first A (position 1), and once counting the first A in the context window of the second A?